Encountering 'Killed' error while running osm2pgrouting to create road network topology via Docker despite increasing swap file size
I am currently at the stage of using the osm2pgrouting tool to create a required topology for a road network. This process involves using Docker and a provided mapconfig.xml file to import specific roads into the database. When i run the necessary command, everything seems to proceed as expected until it abruptly stops with a "Killed" message. I am using Windows and the app Visual studio code for my project.
I happen to know that a colleague of mine who uses a Mac is able to run the command without issue.
I am unfortunately unable to provide with code examples, I can only show the terminal logs.
(About 8-10 minutes after running the command the killed message pops up.)
Connecting to the database
connection success
Dropping tables...
TABLE: ways dropped ... OK.
TABLE: ways_vertices_pgr dropped ... OK.
TABLE: pointsofinterest dropped ... OK.
TABLE: configuration dropped ... OK.
TABLE: nodes dropped ... OK.
TABLE: oways dropped ... OK.
TABLE: relations dropped ... OK.
Creating tables...
TABLE: ways_vertices_pgr created ... OK.
TABLE: ways created ... OK.
TABLE: pointsofinterest created ... OK.
TABLE: configuration created ... OK.
Opening configuration file: mapconfig.xml
Parsing configuration
Exporting configuration ...

Done
Counting lines ...
Done
Opening data file: /data/city-latest.osm     total lines: 32807588
Parsing data

Killed
I've attempted to fix my problem by increasing the swap file size, but the issue still persists.
